# How to add Order by for Specific IDS in sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to add Order by for Specific IDS in sql select query

I have Table_Example like below

```
  ID  Name
  2    Text2
  9   kkk
  10  jj
  1   pp
```

I need output like below

```
  ID  Name
  9   kkk
  1   pp
  10  jj
  2   Text2
```

Comment: you don't mention any logic for ordering.it is hard to understand.

Comment: These are fix values only i have 10 values in this Table that is lookup Table, it will not increase. @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: Hope you understand my requirements now. @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: if you have fix values then go with case expression.

Comment: How can you update your answer. @YogeshSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply Use `Case` expression as below if you have few records & wants to custom orders :

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY(CASE(NAME)
             WHEN 'kkk'
             THEN 1
             WHEN 'pp'
             THEN 2
             WHEN 'jj'
             THEN 3
             WHEN 'Text2'
             THEN 4
         END);
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer from your query. @Yogesh Sharma

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the values in the table to have an order, simply add a sortkey column to the table.

```
alter table lookup_table add column sortkey int;
```

Then fill the sortkeys and use them in your query.

```
select
...  
order by sortkey;
```

Comment: Where is my IDS declaration?, can update clearly. @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your IDs are in the table of course, and so are the names, and so should be the sortkeys. You'd give the record with ID 9 the lowest sortkey and the record with ID 1 the highest and you'd always sort by that sortkey.

Comment: If you update full answer will helpful and I clearly mention above question out should like below. @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: I don't think I have added any information with my comment. Everything was in my answer already. You add a sortkey, fill it, use it. Yogesh Sharma's answer is good, as long as the sort order is only valid for the one query. As soon as you have another query requiring the same sort order, you should add the column instead.